# How to create Circular Cards Wheel Ui in Flutter like Tarot Cards

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to create a Circular Cards wheel UI in Flutter.

[image]
[image]

I've tried many ways including `ListWheelScrollView` but the results are not good as required.

The following are the screenshots of the required output.

[image]

Please Help if you have any idea about it.

Here is the required GIF

[image]

Comment: Would this be helpful?https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_deck